# Settings bundle for iOS, standard settings and icons

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I am trying to use the Settings bundle to set a couple of preferences for my app, that including allowing access to my Location and to configure Notifications. Many apps seem to have a "standard" way of displaying this on a child pane that includes:

1. A standard icon for Location or Notifications.
2. Common verbiage for the setting details.

I cannot find any documentation on how to wire this up in the settings bundle, or any tutorials and am looking for assistance. I am surprised that I cannot even point at an icon for each setting, but since so many apps do this I am SURE I am missing something obvious.

ETA: For an example of what I am talking about, if you look at the Starbucks app there is a setting for Location and Notifications, and that same look-and-feel can be found in many other apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you request location or notification permissions then an entry will automatically be created in the Settings app, under your application name, with the "standard" presentation.

Here is a screen shot of my app after making the necessary requests:

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationType categories:nil]];
```

[image: A view of the location and notification settings.]

Comment: Oh my. Is it that simple? I will test on my app and mark this as answered if so. Does that also apply, then, to allowing access to Photos, Camera, or Contacts? And is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for photos. The information is duplicated on each individual app and in a list in the more specific sections for location, notifications or photos. I'm sure it is documented somewhere, although I found out just through chance.

Comment: Hmm, in the Simulator, this works as described in 8.1, but does not in 7.1. Haven't tried 8.0. Is this a new thing and, if so, how can I achieve functional parity on iOS 7?

Comment: requestAlwaysAuthorization is iOS 8 only, as is registerUserNotificationSettings.I would imagine, but have not tested, that simply using location and notification in iOS 7 will produce the same effect.

Comment: One specific test I made was to access the photo library. In both 7 and 8 I was asked permission to access it, and when I accepted, the app Settings reflected my acceptance on 8, but in 7 it only appeared under the Privacy settings for Photos.

Comment: Have you verified that other apps on iOS have the settings in their respective app settings screen and that it is not jus the standard behaviour for iOS 7?

Comment: In addition to the Photos test, I tried another app I can install on the simulator and it exhibited similar behaviour. So clearly it is a 7 vs. 8 thing, which doesn't help on the "functional parity" front if I wanted Settings to look the same on both platforms. However it clearly addresses my original question, so THANKS!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted. Whilst it doesn't help on function parity at least it's consistent.